# Windows Pods without internet access in Azure Kubernetes Services

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, windows-container

I have created a AKS cluster and deployed Windows Containers pods, but for some reason my Windows Containers are not able to access internet.

For testing purposes, I deployed a Linux Pod and its able to reach it internet.

Is any additional configuration required to allow internet?

My Windows Pods are resolving the DNS addresses, but ping is not responding.

Comment: Any more questions? Does it solve your problem? If it works for you please accept it as the answer.

Comment: Why not accept the answer? Does it not work for you? And I also didn't see any update. So what is the situation?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the pods can access the Internet and Azure also does not forbidden the access from the pods to the Internet. The reason that the ping does not work is the ICMP protocol was forbidden in Windows.

Here is the screenshot of the test:

[image]

And here is the NSG rules for the AKS nodes:

[image]